# Unwanted space between p:dataTable body and footer, how to remove it?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an issue with the footer row that i need to display in primefaces. In UI there is an extra space that comes up between the grid and the footer row which is kind of annoying. Is there anything that is going wrong. Any suggestions are most welcome. Please find my below code.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    >
<h:head>
</h:head>
<body style="height: 90%">
<ui:composition template="template/common/commonPrimefacesLayout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="searchFormForResult" prependId="false">
        <h:inputHidden id="rowId" value="#{MBean.selectedRowId}"></h:inputHidden>   

        <p:accordionPanel style="align:top;margin" prependId="false">
            <p:tab title="Search Items">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                <p:outputLabel for="expenseDesc" value=" Description: " />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="expenseDesc" widgetVar="expenseDesc" value="#{searchMBean.searchCriteria.shortDesc}" style="width:150px" editable="true" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="All" noSelectionOption="false"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{searchMBean.shortDescriptionList}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </p:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton id="Reset" actionListener="#{searchMBean.resetForm}" value="Reset" ajax="false" style="float:right;" onclick="resetSearchForm()"></p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton id="Submit" action="#{searchMBean.search}" value="Submit" ajax="false" style="float:right;"></p:commandButton>

            </p:tab>
        </p:accordionPanel> 
<p:panel> 
<h:outputLabel value="Search Results" style="font-weight: bold;"></h:outputLabel>

<p:dataTable id="SearchResult" var="SearchResult" value="#{searchMBean.searchResult}" selection="#{MBean.itemsSearchResult}" rowKey="#{searchResult.id}" scrollable="true" rowSelectMode="multiple" scrollHeight="65%">
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:5%;"/>
<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Contact Name" />
    </f:facet>

    <h:outputText value="#{mBean.name}" />

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:outputText value="#{mBean.name}" />
    </f:facet> 
</p:column>

<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Contact Address" />
    </f:facet>

    <h:outputText value="#{mBean.addr}" />

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:outputText value="#{mBean.name}" />
    </f:facet>
</p:column>
<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="Actions" />
</f:facet>
<p:commandButton action="#{MBean.display}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-search" title="ViewButton" oncomplete="disableFields('singleRowView');">
<f:param name="itemId" value="#{searchResult.id}"></f:param>
</p:commandButton>
<p:commandButton action="#{MBean.display}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" title="UpdateButton" oncomplete="disableFields('singleRowView');">
<f:param name="itemId" value="#{Result.id}"></f:param>
</p:commandButton>
<p:commandButton id="delete" 
                 icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" 
                 action="#{MBean.ItemRow}" 
                onclick="setSelectedRowId('rowId',#{result.id})"
                 title="GDeleteButton">
                <p:confirm header="Delete Record" 
               message="Are you sure about deleting this record?" 
               icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade">
    <p:commandButton title="GDelYesButton" value="Yes" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"/>
    <p:commandButton title="GDelNoButton" value="No"  onclick="PF('confirmation').hide()" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" />
</p:confirmDialog>


</p:column>

</p:dataTable>
<p:panelGrid id="groupActions"  columns="5">
<p:commandButton action="#{MBean.viewItems}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-search" value="View" title="GViewButton" oncomplete="disableFields('groupView');">
</p:commandButton>
<p:commandButton action="#{MBean.viewItems}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" value="Update" title="GUpdateButton" oncomplete="disableFields('groupView');">
</p:commandButton>
<p:button outcome="createItem" value="Add New" title="AddNewButton"/>

<p:commandButton id="delete" action="#{MBean.delete}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" value="Delete" title="Delete"     >
                            <p:confirm header="Delete Record"   message="Are you sure about deleting this record?"   icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
                        </p:commandButton>


<p:commandButton actionListener="#{searchMBean.resetForm}" value="Cancel" title="Cancel" ajax="false"></p:commandButton>
</p:panelGrid>
                        <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade">
                            <p:commandButton title="Yes" value="Yes"  styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"   />
                            <p:commandButton title="No"  value="No"   styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"   onclick="PF('groupDeleteConfirm').hide()"   />
                        </p:confirmDialog>
</p:panel>




</h:form>

</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

Also please find the image of the behaviour. The extra spaace that is coming between grid and the footer. Please help.
[image]

Comment: Are you using any custom css?

Comment: @starf : no i am not using any custom css.

Comment: How is it if you put some real text in the value, possibly just "&nbsp;"

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar : I had kept it blank but i do contain values in it. even though putting values the space between the grid and footer still remains same.

Comment: So the outputtext is not shown at all?

Comment: can you post the table definition ass well. And the generated code?

Comment: @roel : As suggested i have posted my entire xhtml code. Can you pls help me wid what wrong is being done

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar : The output is shown ofcourse but the distance maintained is same. There is no difference in the layout.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with your code  since I don't have the bean java code. But in your last column you don't have a header defined. And you have a confirmdialog defined. Can you take it out of the datatable?

Comment: I don't understand you sometimes refer to mBean but it is never defined.

Comment: I have the java code with me. Please guide me how to produce the generated code. MBean is the value i have replaced with the actual Bean names before posting it in the site.

Comment: what happens when you only have the first column? Please remove all unnecessary parts of your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59257/discussion-between-roel-and-shirish).

Comment: @Shirish, post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) instead. It's so difficult to test your code with the given piece, without having the bean part and the CSS styles involved. Try to replay it in a project from scratch and post only the relevant parts. That way we'll be able to help you. BTW, you're rendering a whole dialog per column. Don't do that, instead use a single dialog outside the table and populate it with the desired values.